# Does just-ping determine a website's accessibility and/or speed?

Tags: web-hosting, performance, connections, ping

While looking for a webhost I wanted one that had good connectivity around the world, and ran their (shared hosting) test IPs on `just-ping.com`. This is a part of a sample result:

```
 MÃ¼nchen, Germany:     Packets lost (10%)  24.8    24.9    25.1    178.xx.xx.xxx

 Cologne, Germany:  Okay    5.6     5.7     5.8     178.xx.xx.xxx

 New York, U.S.A.:  Packets lost (30%)  80.3    80.4    80.7    178.xx.xx.xxx

 Stockholm, Sweden:     Packets lost (100%)                 178.xx.xx.xxx

 Santa Clara, U.S.A.:   Packets lost (30%)  158.1   158.4   158.7   178.xx.xx.xxx

 Vancouver, Canada:     Packets lost (70%)  189.4   189.5   189.5   178.xx.xx.xxx

 London, United Kingdom:    Packets lost (100%)
```

Am I correct in thinking that hosts with several "Packets lost" messages from different locations have less stable or slower connections than hosts with all "Okays"?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in thinking that hosts with several "Packets lost" messages from different locations have less stable or slower connections

Totally wrong. Packet-loss may happen **everywhere on path** from you to hoster, you (with ping) can only say "*some routes* are *worse for me*, than another" (and slow, overloaded server may have bigger impact on overall delays, than retransmits of packets). Tracerouteote or pathping can identify, where exactly it (packetloss) happens, but anyway, it's (ping) not

- single
- definitive
- good

method of quality measurement of *hosting as service*

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know any tools to test worldwide accessibility? My biggest concern is the site being too slow at a lot of countries or worse, blocking IPS from certain countries. That was the case with my previous host, probably due to a security upgrade.

Comment: We use pingdom for this and are happy with the service tho.  It's not really "World Wide" tho.  They have a LOT of nodes but I believe they are all in Europe and North America.